Modifying Johnson Cook Model in ABAQUS simulations
I am currently simulating a high strain rate impact of commercially pure nickel and found a constitutive equation in DOI: 10.1051/jp4:2006134015. They have a modification of the Johnson Cook model to accommodate the viscous regime at high strain rate and modifies the model to include two additional parameters, D and k:

epsilon 1 is equal to 10^3 s^-1. They have all the parameters for A, B, C, D, m, n, and k, but I don't know how to put this into ABAQUS (I can find that they have the normal JC model, but I don't know how to modify it).
Thank you for your help!

You might just have to write you own UMAT

@Mechanician do you know if there is a beginner-friendly tutorial on how to do that? I haven't done a lot of ABAQUS simulations
